Can we add one set of variables of process to another process in same Linux machine
I have been working on configuring the postgressql pod and secrets fetching from aws secret manager and kept in one pod volume mount using init container.
But while calling pg_ctl -D logfile start command its not recognizing the username & passwords.
Any other approach that we can follow
Tried to source the file within same process but its stating you must specify the POSTGRES_PASSWORD
to non-empty value
